# Non-iterative algorithm for 1D game of life

Tags: arrays, algorithm, iteration, conways-game-of-life

Consider a Boolean array `a[n]`, where each element is a cell. A cell becomes alive (set to `true`) in the next generation if one and only one adjacent cell is alive, otherwise it becomes dead (set to `false`). The first and last cell are considered neighbours.

Given `a[n]`, the array size `n`, and a positive integer `t`, I wish to compute the `a[n]` after t'th generation of evolution, but without using any iterative algorithm on `t`, which can be potentially very large.

What I have observed: if we define `S_k(a[n])` be a *circular shift* of `a[n]` to the right by `k` elements. That is, `a[0]` becomes `a[k]` after one shift if `0 <= k < n`. Define `a[n] ^ b[n]` to be the element-wise xor operation between two boolean arrays. If `w[n]` is a Boolean array, the next generation can be expressed by

```
r(w[n]) = S_{-1}(w[n]) ^ S_1(w[n])
```

The xor operator `^` is associative and commutative. Using this property, the next few generations of `w[n]` can be computed by

```
r^2(w[n]) = ( S_{-2}(w[n]) ^ S_0(w[n]) ) ^ ( S_0(w[n]) ^ S_2(w[n]) )
          = S_{-2}(w[n]) ^ S_2(w[n])
```

If we let `s_j = S_{-j}(w[n]) ^ S_j(w[n])`, there is a pattern

```
r(w[n]) = s_1
r^2(w[n]) = s_2
r^3(w[n]) = s_3 ^ s_1
r^4(w[n]) = s_4
...
r(s_m) = s_{m-1} ^ s_{m+1}
```

Moreover, `s_n = 0` (the array of zeroes) since a full circular shift is the original array. How do I use this to derive a non-iterative expression of `r^t(w[n])`?

Edit: The pattern is

```
[1]
[2]
[1,3]
[4]
[3,5]
[2,6]
[1,3,5,7]
[8]
```

Comment: Why don't you want any iterative algorithm on `t` ? Even if `t` is *very* large, an iterative algorithm in `O(log(t))` would be really efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's represent your input as a column vector `a_0` of size `n` of elements of Z/2Z.

You can compute the next generation vector, `a_1` by using a matrix multiplication:

```
a_1 = M.a_0 = |0 1 0 0 ... 0 0 0|  |a_01|
              |1 0 1 0 ... 0 0 0|  |a_02|
              |0 1 0 1 ... 0 0 0|  |a_03|
              ....
              |0 0 0 0 ... 0 1 0|  |... |
              |0 0 0 0 ... 1 0 1|  |... |
              |0 0 0 0 ... 0 1 0|  |a_0n|
```

Given this recurrence relation, you can compute the generation at time `t` using the formula:

```
a_t = M^t . a_0
```

And you can easily compute `M^t` in `O(n^3.log(t))` using repeated squaring.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no non-iteration way to solve this game as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life#Algorithms) stated. Even the '[Hashlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife)' algorithm is also iterative but with many assisted memory.

But you can use some ways to opt plain iteration algo:

- Use bits rather than int array: This way can save much memory and accelerate speed in some cases.
- Store generations of bits: You can easily compare bits from different generation to find out whether there exists some **repeated patterns** between generations, in which cases, no more calculation is needed any more. Considering you only have one dimension, the chance might be very high.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to uncover more of the pattern...

Does it go on like this:

```
1
 2 
1 3
   4
  3 5
 2   6
1 3 5 7
       8
      7 9
     6   a
    5     b
   4       c
  3   ???   d
 2           e
1 3 5 7 9 b d f
               g
```

If so, the simplest way seems to be to calculate r for the closest power of two <= t, then do the same for the remainder (t' = t-2^n) etc, so you'd be down to O(log(t)). If the ??? area is actually empty, you should be able to limit the steps to 3 (avoid 2^n-1 by calculating the value before, then go a single step).

Comment: Yes. The pattern does go like this. The ??? region is not empty though, since the next step of `[6,a]` is `[5,7,9,b]`. I am not sure what you mean by going to a previous power of two.

Comment: Assume you want to go to t=99. Calculate r^64 which should have only one term (s64) if I understand the pattern correctly, then r^96 from there by applying s32, then s2 then s1. It's still iterative, but you loop over log(t) instead of t. –